# To be a sub-4 marathon finisher, you must complete a sub-2 half marathon.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, puzzle

Came across this statement in a running group, so I'm curious whether this is true. More formally,

> Let $x(t)$ be the runner's distance (in km) at time $t$ and $x$ is a weakly increasing function. Given that $x(4) \geq 42.2$, there must be an interval $[a, a+2]$ with $a \in [0,2]$ such that $x(a+2)-x(a) \geq 21.1$.

Comment: Yes. $a=0$ or $a=2$ works, since if neither worked, we'd have $x(4) = x(4)-x(2)+x(2)-x(0) < 21.1+21.1 = 42.2$.

Comment: I assumed $x(0) = 0$ in the above.

Comment: Duh. So simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The interesting variant is actually: for what $x \in (0,1)$ is it possible that you run a $4$ hr marathon without any $4x$ stretch that covers $42.2x$?  E.g. it is possible to run a $4$ hr marathon without a sub-$3$ hr $\frac34$-marathon.

Comment: Hm... here's another variant I thought of: is there a maximum $n$ such that if you run a marathon in 4 hours, you need to run distance $42.2/n$ within $4/n$ hours.

Comment: @Art - if your variant, if $n$ is an integer, then the same logic by mathworker21 applies, i.e. just chop the course into $n$ equal pieces.  If $n$ is not an integer, then your variant is the same as mine.  :)